# type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Client' in type cast in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to get the Client name from the Api using fromMap() method as shown bellow:

```
factory Order.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
  return Order(
   created_at: Tracker.decode(map['created_at']),
   id: map['id'],
   updated_at: Tracker.decode(map['updated_at']),
   total_price: map['total_price'],
   status: map['status'],
   client: map['client']


  );
 }
```

client is an object of Client Model ..
I got the following error:
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Client' in type cast...

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to assign a data of type `Map<String, dynamic>` to the `client` which seems to the of type `Client`.

You need to convert the `map['client']` into the `Client` by using `Client.fromMap(map['client'])` assuming you have the Client model

Comment: I knew the logic yes, but I didn't know the syntax, it worked, Thank you!